# General solution of a second order non homogenous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Three solutions of a certain second order non-homogenous linear equation in $\mathbb{R}$ are $$\phi_{1}(t)=t^2, \phi_{2}(t)=t^2 + e^{2t}, \phi_{3}(t) = 1+ t^2 + e^{2t}$$
Find the general solution of this equation.

My solution is this: I find the wronskian for each possible pair $12,23,13$ and if Wronskian is non-zero and then I take the general solution as that pair + the third solution. Is this fine or am I missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to find two linearly independent solutions $y_1,y_2$ to the homogeneous equation, then the general solution to the non-homogeneous equation is $y_P+c_1y_1+c_2y_2$, where $y_P$ is a particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation (e.g. $y_P(t)=\phi_1(t)=t^2$).

By linearity, the difference of two solutions to the non-homogeneous equation is a solution to the homogeneous equation. So we can take $y_1(t)=\phi_3(t)-\phi_2(t)=1$ and $y_2(t)=\phi_2(t)-\phi_1(t)=e^{2t}$ as our solutions to the homogeneous equation. It is easy to check that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent.

Thus the general solution to the non-homogeneous equation is $$y(t)=t^2+c_1+c_2e^{2t},$$

for some arbitrary constants $c_1,c_2$.